# payment method is not able to call in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, payment-gateway

am new to swift, working on payment getaways
now I have to pass values to paymentmethod but, am not clear to how to cal, I have to call sendmethod inside button click in swift.how can I call method outside the nsboject pass the parameters in swift

```
@protocol avantServiceDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)TransactionResponse:(NSString *)status;
@end
@interface avantService : NSObject{

}
+ (avantService *)sharedController;
-(void)SetData:(NSString *) Merchant_Key :(NSString *)Merchant_ID :(NSString *) SuccessUrl_Key :(NSString *) FailureUrl_Key :(NSString *)ServerUrl_Key;

-(BOOL)Transactiondata:(NSString *)Transaction_Detail :(NSString *)Payment_Details :(NSString*)Card_Detail :(NSString *)Customer_Detail :(NSString *)Bill_data :(NSString *)Ship_details :(NSString *)Item_Detail :(NSString *)Other_Detail :(NSString *)Coin_Detail :(NSString *)Upi_Detail :(NSString *)Imps_Detail;

-(void) showTransactionPageViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;

@property (nonatomic,retain) id <avantServiceDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

before I called when object is inside

```
@interface avantService : NSObject{

- (void)createRequestWithPaymentParam:(PayUModelPaymentParams * _Nonnull)paymentParam forPaymentType:(NSString * _Nonnull)paymentType withCompletionBlock:(void (^ _Nonnull)(NSMutableURLRequest * _Nonnull, NSString * _Nonnull))paramCompletionBlock;
}

 let createRequest = PayUCreateRequest()
    createRequest.createRequest(withPaymentParam: self.paymentParams, forPaymentType: PAYMENT_PG_NET_BANKING) { (request, error) in
}
```

I called inside the object

but how can I call the SetData method

Comment: I changed language tag from swift to objective-c, if that was wrong please clarify why because it's hard to see how this is relevant to swift.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson am working on swift, that method I have to call because of that. bellow method I worked for other payment getaway it was working same like that I want to do

Comment: Start by writing proper Objective-C method names. `-(void)SetData:(NSString *) Merchant_Key :(NSString *)Merchant_ID :(NSString *) SuccessUrl_Key :(NSString *) FailureUrl_Key :(NSString *)ServerUrl_Key;` should be something like `- (void)setData(NSString *)merchantKey merchantID:(NSString *)merchantID successURLKey:(NSString *)successURLKey failureURLKey:(NSString *)failureURLKey serverURLKey:(NSString *)serverURLKey`. Now you can call it from Swift.

Comment: @rmaddy thankq i will try